# Figure of $SO(10)$ grand unified theory in $E_6$ from Wikipedia

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, representation-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

In this [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO(10)#cite_note-3) from Wikipedia, it shows that the representations of particles of $SO(10)$ grand unified theory, their patterns of charges for particles in the $SO(10)$ model, rotated to show the embedding in $E_6$.

### Questions

1. This figure seems to show the 5 axes, including the $B$, $W$, $W'$, $g^8$, and $g^3$. How are these 5 axes related to the previous question for the 3 axes? [Figure of $SO(10)$ grand unified theory from Wikipedia](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/643743/42982)
2. How is the $SO(10)$ model rotated to be the embedding in $E_6$? reading from this figure.
3. Look into the color patterns closely, it seems that the

- orange and red are on two flipped sides of the same object.
- purple and blue are on two flipped sides of the same object.
- yellow and green are on two flipped sides of the same object.

What do these two sides of colors on the flipped sides imply?

[image]